# How to show popup open in iframe on another full page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem i create a html table using Angularjs with popup now i want to show this table on iframe everything is ok but the popup window which show graph open in following div i want to open it on whole page 
my out put like this 
[image: Popup open in respective panel only but i want to open it on full page]

and i want like this
[image: Open popup window like this but popup only open in panel]

my code as follows ,Stock.html code which i call in iframe

```
<div ng-controller="StockCtrl">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-full-width"  ng-init="firstCall()" id="Stocktable1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:left;width:auto;">Name</th>
                <th class="hidden-xs" style="text-align:center;width:auto;">Index</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;">Up Down</th>
                <th class="hidden-xs" style="text-align:center;width:auto;">52 Week(Min-Max)</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;width:auto;">As On</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="CU in CustomerList">
                <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalstock" ng-click="$parent.active =CU;" style="font-size:10px;color:#007DFF;">{{CU.Name}}</a></td>
                <td class="hidden-xs" style="text-align:right;font-size:10px;">{{CU.Index | number}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:center;width:auto;font-size:10px;" ng-style="set_color(CU.Up_Down)"><div ng-if="CU.perChange==' '">{{CU.Up_Down}}</div><div ng-if="CU.perChange!=' '">{{CU.Up_Down + ' (' + CU.perChange+ ')' }}</div></td>
                <td class="hidden-xs" style="text-align:center;font-size:10px;">{{CU.HighLow}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:center;font-size:10px;">{{CU.As_On}}</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>
    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="modalstock" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" ng-model="name">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog modal-lg">

                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{active.Name}}</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body" style="height:500px !important;">
                                        <!--<canvas id="barChart" class="full-width"></canvas>-->
                                        <iframe ng-src="{{active.Name.replace('&','AND') + '.html'}}" class="frame" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" onload="" allowtransparency="false" height="500px"></iframe>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-o" data-dismiss="modal">
                                            Close
                                        </button>
                                        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                            Save changes
                                        </button>-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

and then i open the whole page in iframe by this code :{{mypage.Table_src}} equal to stock.html page which contain html table and pop up

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <iframe src="{{myPage.Table_src}}" class="frame" id="Productionboxframe" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" onload="" allowtransparency="false" height="500px"></iframe>
</div>
```

please help me

Comment: "table-full-width" probably this class my affect, and that is why this popup show in full page

Comment: `i want to open it on whole page` what exactly does that mean?

Comment: Thanks Dipak for you swift response actually i call stock.html page in iframe where popup working when i click on option popup open but popup open in specific panel where i call this page in iframe i want to show pop up on full page 
stock.html page contain htmltable with popup user click on table value and it open popup working fine 
index.html in which i call stock.html page in iframe in panel when user click on any link it open only in specific panel not on page i want to open on full page

Comment: If I understand you right. You don't want a PopUp/Modal to display your iframe data? You want to open it on page in full view port scale?

Comment: My popup open when user click on table and in popup graph show i want same scenario but  want to show that popup on full page not in a specifc panel where frame is look the second image what i want

Answer (score 1):

You can use position fixed. Position fixed position an element relative to screen's  viewport.

Comment: The popup modal on Stock.html page i want to open it on index.html full page but it only open within panel-body ,my requirement is to show it on full page

Comment: OK I will look into this on weekend and let you know the solution.

Comment: Thanks @Pankaj Kumar Singh

Answer (score 0):

if you use uibmodal you can add appendTo

`$uibModal.open({ appendTo: angular.element($(window.parent.document).find('body')), .......})`